# Postgresql - Query all time-series rows in a table

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY time;
```

The above query will query all rows sitting in `table_1`, while sorting all the rows by a column `time`. However, if the size of the table gets millions of rows, fetching all rows in a table will be inefficient with the addition of `ORDER BY time`. However luckily, the table I have is a time-series table that uses `TimescaleDB` extension, and all rows are inserted in timely order.

In this case, what would be the most efficient way of fetching everything in a table, while ensuring the resulting query is ordered by `time`?

Do I just delete `ORDER BY time`? If I remove this, can I be sure that the resulting query will ALWAYS be in a order of `time`?

Also, I've heard that PostgreSQL has some driver issues when fetching all rows in a table, because its optimized for querying small fraction of data in a table. How can I optimize the performance?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to ensure the order of a dataset returned by a `SELECT` statement without using an explicit `ORDER BY` clause; this is true even if the data is stored within the table in an ordered manner. If you must have the data ordered, it is safest to define an `ORDER BY` clause.

Running a `SELECT *` against a `TimescaleDB` Hypertable isn't going to be efficient. `TimescaleDB` stores data in chunks within a hypertable, the idea being that you time-bound your query such that it hits a single specific chunk, which results in optimal performance. When you run a query that must hit all records in the table, it now has to look at all data contained within all of the chunks, and the only way to do this is via a sequential scan.

This leads to your question about PostgreSQL and fetching all rows. PostgreSQL leverages parallel sequential scans when a large portion of a table is going to be hit by a query. While this is going to yield better performance than a single-shot sequential scan, it's still not going to be as quick as index scan pulling a subset of data would be against the same table.

What is the reasoning behind needing to query all rows in the table? By virtue that any SQL engine would have to look at each row at least once in order to ensure that all rows are returned, there is no way that a `SELECT *` is ever going to be able to leverage the lookup advantages associated with hashing and indexing.